# Old '80s or '90s anime about a guy with a crystal in his hand

Tags: story-identification, anime

A Russian guy in a Discord is asking us to help him find an old anime he saw on a VHS, maybe from the '80s or '90s.

His English isn't great so it's hard to describe exactly what he's looking for, but he's describing it as a dark, cyberpunk-esque anime about a young guy who sees a spaceship falling out of the sky or just flying really low. The guy is being chased by some other people, so he flies up to the falling ship and finds an older guy dying in there. The older guy talks to him and ends up transferring a round crystal to his hand. The guy in the server says it looked like really digital lines and stripes to show it was being transferred. He doesn't really know how to translate it well.

We've already shown him stuff like *Xam'd: Lost Memories* and *Tekkaman Blade*, but he says those aren't the one he's looking for. If you have any idea, lemme know.

Comment: We like to ask follow-up questions here, to help clarify any ambiguities in the description, where possible. A few such questions that spring to mind here are:  1) Can the guy who watched this confirm whether it was a movie or a series? 2) How precisely did the "guy" in the description fly up to the falling ship? Could he fly on his own, or did he use a vehicle? If a vehicle, then what type? 3) Also, can the guy who watched this confirm the approximate year in which he did so? (Sometimes people guess incorrectly as to how old something they watched actually is.)

Comment: If anyone posts a correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

Answer (score 17):

Is this ***[Lensman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lensman_(1984_film))*** (1984)...?

> *Lensman: Secret of the Lens*, known in Japan as *Sci-Fi New Century Lensman* (SF新世紀 レンズマン, *Esuefu Shinseiki Renzuman*), is a 1984 Japanese animated film based on the *[Lensman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lensman_series)* novels by E. E. Smith. Most of the CGI sequences were created by the Japan Computer Graphics Lab (JCGL). It was dubbed into English and released in the United States in 1990.

The story is set in the 25th century, by which time humanity has colonised other worlds and established a space defence force known as the Galactic Patrol. The Galactic Patrol are at war with an alliance of hostile aliens known as the Boskone Empire, who wish to dominate the galaxy.

One of the Galactic Patrol's operatives has recently acquired a "neutralising formula" from the Boskone which will enable the Galactic Patrol to defend themselves against a deadly new Boskone "DNA weapon." As that operative is returning to the Galactic Patrol Base to deliver the data to Admiral Haynes, his ship, the Brittania, sustains damage from a Boskone attack, and he himself is mortally wounded.

The actual protagonist is Kimball "Kim" Kinnison, a young man from the human colony world of Mqueie. Around five minutes into the film, we see him piloting a small spacecraft not far from Mqueie. Soon after, he's alerted to the presence of a larger, unidentified vessel -- the Brittania --  which is flying out of control and on course to crash into a population centre on Mqueie. Kim boards the Brittania, hoping to prevent this disaster, and manages to land the ship safely. He then helps the dying pilot out of the vessel.

It turns out that the pilot is a Lensman -- specially chosen members of the Galactic Patrol who have a glassy convex disc called a Lens implanted in the back of their left hands. This particular Lens contains the formula needed to mount a defence against the Boskone's new weapon, so just before the Lensman dies, he transfers the Lens to Kim's left hand and asks him to take it to Admiral Haynes, telling him what's at stake if he doesn't. Soon after, Mqueie itself comes under attack from the Boskone, who're still after that Lens to prevent the data it contains from reaching the Galactic Patrol Base.

You can view the scene where the Lens is transferred to Kim's hand at around the 11:33 mark in the video below. The visuals shown during the transference do include what could be described as "digital lines," rendered in somewhat *Tron*-like CGI.

Comment: I'm not sure of the cause of the ambiguity on the timestamp, try more like [12:13](https://youtu.be/U2I2P1uNSGU?t=733)

Comment: @Orangutech - I timestamped the video in my answer to play from the 11:33 mark, because that's what I judged to be the beginning of the relevant scene, and if you play the video from that point, you get to hear more relevant dialogue that helps adds further context to what is occurring. That said, you'll still see the transference either way, so it's down to each individual viewer to decide when they want to play the video from.